# Is anyone embedded aqua-sim-ng with ns-3.29?

Tags: c++, ns-3

I had tried to configure aqua-sim-ng (according to aqua-sim-ng documentation would only work on ns-3.25,ns-3.26 and ns-3.27) with ns-3.29. I am getting an compiling error which is attached below. Please help how can i solve those compiling error.

```
In file included from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-phy.h:29:0,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-net-device.h:38,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing.h:35,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing-vbf.h:24,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing-vbf.cc:21:
../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-channel.h:67:20: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual uint32_t ns3::AquaSimChannel::GetNDevices() const’
   virtual uint32_t GetNDevices (void) const;
                    ^
In file included from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-channel.h:24:0,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-phy.h:29,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-net-device.h:38,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing.h:35,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing-vbf.h:24,
                 from ../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing-vbf.cc:21:
./ns3/channel.h:68:23: error:   overriding ‘virtual std::size_t ns3::Channel::GetNDevices() const’
   virtual std::size_t GetNDevices (void) const = 0;
                   ^

Waf: Leaving directory `/home/jay/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.29/ns-3.29/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'ns3-aqua-sim-ng' failed with exit status 1:
        {task 140292841097768: cxx aqua-sim-routing-vbf.cc -> aqua-sim-routing-vbf.cc.1.o}
['/usr/bin/g++', '-O0', '-ggdb', '-g3', '-Wall', '-Werror', '-std=c++11', '-fstrict-aliasing', '-Wstrict-aliasing', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-I.', '-I..', '-DNS3_BUILD_PROFILE_DEBUG', '-DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE', '-DNS3_LOG_ENABLE', '-DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1', '-DHAVE_IF_NETS_H=1', '-DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H=1', '-DHAVE_PACKET_H=1', '-DHAVE_SQLITE3=1', '-DHAVE_IF_TUN_H=1', '../src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing-vbf.cc', '-c', '-o/home/jay/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.29/ns-3.29/build/src/aqua-sim-ng/model/aqua-sim-routing-vbf.cc.1.o']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between the types `uint32_t` and `std::size_t`. Change all the occurrences of `uint32_t` to `std::size_t` in `aqua-sim-channel.h` and `aqua-sim-channel.cc` .